# Pagination when I use wp_query with 'post_type' => array('test','test')

Tags: php, wordpress

When I use 2 or 3 different post_types I can't make the pagination. This only show me 2 posts, the pagination appears but when I make click on it still show me the same 2 posts.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ?>
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('pt1','pt2'),
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'paged' => $paged
);
$general = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php while($general->have_posts()) : $general->the_post(); $imagen = get_the_post_thumbnail_url()?>

    <div class="vc_col-12 vc_col-lg-6 float-left post-loop">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        </a>
        <p class="text-muted"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo the_time('d'); ?> <?php echo the_time('M'); ?>  </p>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
<ul>
    <li><?php  previous_posts_link('&laquo; previous', $general->max_num_pages); ?></li>
    <li><?php next_posts_link('next &raquo;', $general->max_num_pages); ?></li>
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compared your code to the very similar *working* code on one of my websites. The only real difference I could find was that I have this line (which you don't have)...

```
$number_of_posts = get_option('posts_per_page', 2);
```

...inserted directly *after* (= below) this one (which you have):

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Try that, I hope that helps...